# Delegate compiled with Expression.Block keeps throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, lambda, expression

I'm trying to build an Expression that assigns multiple properties to a given object, but after calling the compiled delegate, it keeps throwing a `NullReferenceException` from within the lambda's body:

```cs
var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "a");
var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(B), "b");
var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(C), "c");

LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(A));
GotoExpression returnExpression =
    Expression.Return(returnTarget, a, typeof(A));
LabelExpression returnLabel = Expression.Label(
    returnTarget, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(A)));

var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<A, B, C, A>>(
    Expression.Block(
        typeof(A),
        new[] { a, b, c },
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Property(a, typeof(A).GetProperty("B")),
            b),
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Property(a, typeof(A).GetProperty("C")),
            c),
        returnExpression,
        returnLabel
    ), 
    a, b, c);

Func<A, B, C, A> func = expression.Compile();

// Calling func throws a NullReferenceException
A result = func(new A(), new B(), new C());
```

I assume I wrote the `Expression.Block` incorrectly, but what am I doing wrong here exactly?

Comment: It would be useful to know which line throws the exception.

Comment: @Jon: See my comment on the last line: "// Calling func throws a NullReferenceException". Also note that including the stack trace doesn't give you extra information. The call stack end inside the generated lambda.

Comment: Yes, but at the very very least you can try commenting out stuff to quickly pinpoint the culprit. It's not a big lambda.

Comment: @Jon: I already did my best to minimize it.

Comment: The assignments are failing, presumably because the value of parameter "a" is null.

Comment: @RobEpstein: How can parameter "a" be null? I supply `new A()` as value.

Comment: I've edited your post with additional code that illustrates that the value of the parameter is null. Unfortunately it's not closer to explaining why it is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace the line

```
new[] { a, b, c },
```

with

```
new ParameterExpression[] {},
```

The second argument to `Expression.Block` is supposed to define block-scoped variables - but you already supplied the parameters a, b and c as function level parameters in the last argument to `Expression.Lambda`.